# How to fix error "undefined variable:sin" in plotting in gnuplot?

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot, undefined-variable

I am plotting in 2D on gnuplot through Ubuntu. When defining my equation for 'radius of curvature' a function of theta=x of variables sin and cos functions, respectively, I get an error message saying 'undefined variable: sin' or cos. I am simply defining the variable R=1 in the equation then setting

```
f(x) = R*sin(x)*(1+4*cos**2*(x)**(1.5)) / 2*(2*sin**2*(x)+3*cos**2*(x))
```

then saying plot f(x).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: gnuplot does not recognize `cos**2(x)` as meaning `cos(x)**2`. It thinks you are squaring a variable named cos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your function

`f(x) = R*sin(x)*(1+4*cos**2*(x)**(1.5)) / 2*(2*sin**2*(x)+3*cos**2*(x))`

you should actually get an error `undefined variable: cos`,

Your intention probably was:

`f(x) = R*sin(x)*(1+4*cos(x)**2**(1.5)) / 2*(2*sin(x)**2 + 3*cos(x)**2)`

or maybe

`f(x) = R*sin(x)*(1+4*cos(x)**2**(1.5)) / (2*(2*sin(x)**2 + 3*cos(x)**2))`

where I'm not sure whether in the first part this should really be:
`cos(x)**2**1.5`

or maybe: `R*sin(x)*(1+4*cos(x)**2)**1.5`

Mind the parentheses.

Comment: Yes, this is what worked. I realized that the value of the power comes immediately after. Thankyou